# Duplicate records

Tags: nhibernate

I am using nHibernate for db persistence.  I have a one-to-many relationship defined between 2 tables.  When I query and try to get data, I am getting the correct number of rows from the "many" table, but the rows are duplicates of the first row returned.

table1 (one), table2 (many).  I create a criteria query to get a certain record from table1.  I then expect to get all associated records from table2.  ie, table1 holds orders, table2 holds items.  I query table1 to get an order which has 4 items.  I expect to see each of those 4 items from table2, but all I am seeing is the 1st item repeated 4 times.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem to be a composite key on table2. I included the composite-id mapping and it worked fine.

Thanks to the code [here](http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2009/03/19/nhibernate-and-the-composite-id.aspx) to get me through the Equals and GetHashCode errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate performs join to execute your query. To get distinct results use DistinctEntityRootTransformer.

Comment: But the query that is running it is returning the correct data, which leads me to believe it may be a mapping issue.  Does that sound correct?